Не работает интернет Arch Linux Gnome
Решил всё-таки поставить Linux и начал не с Ubuntu, как многие рекомендуют, а с Arch.
После установки - захожу в браузер и вижу, что нет интернета. Оказалось, что это не у меня, а у самого компьютера. NetworkManager не запущен.
Как мне сделать на Arch-Linux интернет?
Ну, вот:
lspci -v
Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (Rev 99)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
Memory at f1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: denied
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169

sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd
Loaded: (source; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: active (running)
TriggeredBy: systemd-networkd.socket
Status: "Processing requests..."
Tasks: 1 (limit: 8494)
FD Store: 0 (limit: 512)
Memory: 3.2M (peak: 3.5M)
CPU: 33ms

sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved
Loaded: loaded (source: enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: active (running)
Status: "Processing requests..."
Tasks: 1 (limit: 8494)
Memory: 3.8M (peak: 3.9M)
CPU: 60ms


Вы выполнили действия из руководства? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Wireless

В chroot-окружении включить NetworkManager
